# Loading JSON with Power Query and including HYPERLINK

Tags: json, excel, powerquery

I'm loading JSON data into Excel using Power Query, all good.

Some of the columns need to be HYPERLINK(), which is just plain text in the JSON, and imports fine. However the formula does not convert; it's just plain text in the sheet once loaded.

I can insert a ' before the formula, and then macro a find-replace, but is there a better way to do this, and have formulas work in the sheet once the data is loaded?

Comment: https://www.thebiccountant.com/2017/09/12/powerquery-return-clickable-hyperlinks-to-excel/

Comment: I literally mentioned doing this in my post.

Comment: My bad. Ignore me then. Thanks. There is no better way to do it, other then perhaps not including the ' and replacing = with another =